# 'int' object is not iterable Python

Tags: python, pyqt5

Выдает ошибку

```
    i = 0
    for i in ui.tableWidget.rowCount():
        print(ui.tableWidget.item(i,0))
```

Не могу понять что не так? `ui.tableWidget.rowCount()` возвращает `int`

Comment: В питоне это делается через итератор, то есть надо использовать range(): `for i in range(ui.tableWidget.rowCount()):...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объяснение ошибки

> 'int' object is not iterable

`ui.tableWidget.rowCount()` - это число строк вашей таблицы. Скажем, 9.

Тогда из вашей команды

```
for i in ui.tableWidget.rowCount():
```

получится

```
for i in 9:
```

9 не является ни списком, ни кортежей, ни словарем, по котором бы было возможно проходить (итерировать) - это целое число, т.е. объект типа `int` (от «integer», целое число).

---

Теперь к вашей программе:

1. Первая строка вашей программы (`i = 0`) не нужна.
2. Чтобы не надо было всегда писать долгое `ui.tableWidget`, вы можете присвоить тому имя, например `table = ui.tableWidget`.
3. Вы хотите итерировать через *порядковые номера* строк, значит от `0` до `rowCount() - 1`. Дла этого фунция `range()`.

Итак, всё может выглядеть так:

```
table = ui.tableWidget
for i in range(table.rowCount()):
    print(table.item(i, 0))
```

Answer (score 2):

после in должно быть то, по чему можно итерироваться. Например, диапазон. Это может быть так

```
for i in range(0,ui.tableWidget.rowCount()):
```

и теперь i пробежит весь диапазон.

В 2 питоне лучше было писать xrange, хотя range также работает (но не так эффективно).